# QThread::currentThread () vs QObject::thread()

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qobject

I am looking for an answer if there is any difference between these two functions, aside from the constness of the first one:

```
QThread * QObject::thread() const
QThread * QThread::currentThread()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are quite different.

`QThread * QObject::thread() const` returns the thread in which a particular `QObject` lives.

`QThread * QThread::currentThread()` Returns a pointer to a QThread which manages the currently executing thread.

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{

};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MyClass * obj = new MyClass();
    QThread thread2;
    obj->moveToThread(&thread2);
    thread2.start();

    qDebug() << "The current thread is " << QThread::currentThread();
    qDebug() << "The thread2 address is " << &thread2;
    qDebug() << "The object is in thread " << obj->thread();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Sample output:

> The current thread is  QThread(0x1436b20)
>   The thread2 address is  QThread(0x7fff29753a30)
>   The object is in thread  QThread(0x7fff29753a30)

Answer (score 4):

They do two different things.
`QThread::currentThread()` is a static function that returns a pointer to the thread which it is called from, ie. current thread.

`QObject::thread()` returns a pointer to the thread in which this object lives in.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same although they might return the same result.

1st one returns the thread that the QObject lives in.

2nd one returns the currently executing thread.